# Javascript mousemove empty event handler leaking memory?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, event-handling, addeventlistener, event-listener

I am working with event listeners/handlers in the following way:

```
    var _builder_canvas = document.getElementById("Builder");

    mouseMove = function() {
    }

    initBuilder = function( ) {
         // Add mouse listener events
         _builder_canvas.addEventListener( 'mousemove', mouseMove, true);
    }
```

With 'initBuilder' being called with the onload handler of the main document.

Even with an empty function as above, when I run this code in Chrome (23.0.1271.64) or FF (16.0.2) there is memory allocated every time the mouse moves that is never released.

I know that you always need to remove the event listeners to avoid memory leaks, but how does one do that when it is a mousemove handler? The handler needs to be active the entire time the page is open.

I have also noticed that adding a listener/handler in a similar fashion for mouseup or mousedown does not result in any extra memory allocation.

Am I missing something fundamental here? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you've pared down your code too much. :-) We need to see what the `mousemove` handler is doing to help you understand why memory related to calling it isn't being released. If it's really empty as shown, the memory related to the call will be eligible for release immediately, and Chrome's quite good at optimizing simple cases like that. My guess is that your handler does something which (inadvertently) ties things up.

Comment: The symptoms sound like each _mousemove_ is registering an additional event handler or some other variable that won't be GCd.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : That's the thing, I experience the memory issues when I have an empty function, just as above with nothing happening in the handler.

Comment: @PaulS. : That's what I don't get, the above code is the extent of everything I am doing. No additional handler being registered (unless the browser is doing something on its own) and there are no variables in my handler...

Comment: It's possible that memory is not leaking at all but only appears to be leaking. Chrome will garbage collect when chrome wants to garbage collect. It doesn't immediately toss stuff out as soon as it goes out of scope, it tosses it out when it believes it's most efficient. How are you measuring this memory leak?

Comment: @Nucleon : Good point. I am not measuring it in any way other than observationally. That may be the case. But if I sit and move the mouse around over the Canvas, the memory usage will continually go up by several k or more and never decrease. Do you think this is just an inaccurate reflection of the memory usage (Task Manager)?

Comment: @user1812575: It's normal in a garbage-collected environment to see memory get reclaimed much later than the point where you know it's not being used anymore. I'm a bit surprised you're seeing that with Chrome, because it's so good at doing aggressive stack-based stuff if you don't create closures, but hey, the joy of a GC system is that 99.9% you don't have to worry about how it works. (That last 0.1% is a *bitch*, though.)

Comment: On Chrome the GC tends to start collecting on the page when you have deselected the corresponding tab. If memory grows, then there is probably no need yet for the GC to start.

Comment: Here's an interesting article about tracking memory leaks in Chrome. If you try this what are your results? https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling

Comment: @pimvdb : Thanks. I see that if I switch tabs the GC does start. Forgive my ignorance about the GC, but is there some other trigger that will kick it in if a user interacts with my page for a long period of time, or will the usage continue to grow until the tab is deselected?

Comment: @user1812575: The only way is to run Chrome with the `--js-flags="--expose-gc"` flag and then call `gc()`, but that's obviously not something you can force the user to do. That said, if the GC decides not to start, then it's probably just not necessary and doing GC would only hurt performance. The GC will start if memory is really getting an issue, you can trust it :)

Comment: @pimvdb : Thanks, that makes me feel better :)

Comment: @Nucleon : Thanks for pointing that out. I actually haven't used those profiling tools before, very helpful. I don't see anything too out of the ordinary except that the retained size of mouseMove is much higher than similarly empty functions set as handlers for mouseup and mousedown. I'm hoping it's something along the lines of what pimvdb was saying and the GC just isn't starting for some reason. It still seems strange to me though!

Answer (score 0):

If you record memory usage using devtools > timeline, you'll see that memory is well deallocated after that the event is fired.